# Code from GOPL: concurrent web crawler

Tags: go

Here is an example code from the book "The Go Programming Language" by Donovan and Kernighan. It's about a simple concurrent web crawler.

https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/crawl3/findlinks.go

When I put this part (in the `main` function)

```
seen := make(map[string]bool)
for list := range worklist {
    for _, link := range list {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

in front of

```
for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
    go func() {
        for link := range unseenLinks {
          ...
        }
    }()
}
```

the code does not work. Why is this?

Comment: "the code does not work" --- this is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

If you swap those - `for list := range worklist {` line is executed before you start goroutine.

And because `worklist` is a non-closed empty channel - you're blocked there forever.

Whereas, while they are in the right order - goroutines send to the `worklist` and your main thread reads from it.